# Dot product in index notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, vectors, notation, linear-algebra

This is a question about a small exercise I am trying to do in order to check if I am correct. Such type of quantities can appear in propagators in QFT. Since I am not an index expert I need some assistance.

I have the following quantity
$$ (ia_{\mu} + b_{\mu}) $$
and I want to bring it to the form such that it is proportional to either $(a^2 + b^2)$ (up to some $i$) or $(a+b)^2$ (again up to some $i$). I do the following

a) $\,\,\, (ia_{\mu} + b_{\mu}) = i(a_{\mu} - ib_{\mu} )$ and then I have
$$
i^2(a_{\mu}- ib_{\mu} )(a^{\mu}+ ib^{\mu} ) = i^2(a^2 + ia_{\mu}b^{\mu}-ia^{\mu}b_{\mu} - ib^{2}) = i^2(a^2+b^2)
$$

b) $$
i^2(a_{\mu} - ib_{\mu})(a^{\mu} - ib^{\mu})= i^2(a^2 - ia_{\mu}b^{\mu} - ia^{\mu}b_{\mu} + i^2b^2) = i^2(a^2 - 2ia_{\mu}b^{\mu}  + i^2b^2) =i^2(a-ib)^2
$$
I would like your help to know if I do these operations correctly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, the operations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

These two formulae must give the same result. I think there are some mistakes in your calculation.
The result a) is correct.
a) $(ia_{\mu} + b_{\mu}) = i(a_{\mu} - ib_{\mu} )$ and then it is
$$
i^2(a_{\mu}- ib_{\mu} )(a^{\mu}+ ib^{\mu} ) = i^2(a^2 + ia_{\mu}b^{\mu}-ia^{\mu}b_{\mu} - ib^{2}) = i^2(a^2+b^2)
$$
.
But result b) is wrong. The correct result is
$$
(ia_{\mu} + b_{\mu})(ia^{\mu} - b^{\mu})= i^2(a^2 + ia_{\mu}b^{\mu} - ia^{\mu}b_{\mu} + i^2b^2) = i^2(a^2  + i^2b^2) $$.
Of course these methods give the same answer.

Comment: Yes, the result b) seemed wrong since I made a typo. I meant to calculate $(ia_{\mu}-b_{\mu})(ia^{\mu}-b^{\mu})$ and not $(ia_{\mu}-b_{\mu})(ia^{\mu}+b^{\mu})$ in that case.

Comment: @Marion Then b) is right. And the you  can calculate the invariant using a)

Comment: Why not using b)? In principle I can use both right? The problem of course is that b) (sitting in the denominator of some propagator) will give me a double pole.